# I need to create a 'touch' function in node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

I'm trying to mimic a terminal in node so I need to create a 'touch' function in node.js and I can't find anything that specifically uses touch. How can I set that up?

I've used a couple different things in the past but they keep getting kicked back because I'm not actually using 'fs.touch' or whatever it is.

this was my first attempt.

```
module.exports.touch = (filename, err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    } else {
        fs.openSync(filename, 'w');
        `open filename`
    }
};
```

this was my most recent attempt

```
module.exports.touch = (filename, callback) => {
  open(filename, 'w', (err, fd) => {
    err ? callback(err) : close(fd, callback);
  });
};
```

The second one was essentially what they wanted because it did create a touch function but again they want me to actually use `fs.touch` but I cant find anything about it.

Comment: There is no `fs.touch` method. Do you have a custom fs module in house (something like `fs-extra` which extends the fs functionality)? Perhaps there is a `fs.touch` method implemented there already, or they want you to implement it there. I'm just guessing here, you need to get clarification from your colleague.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger I got a little more clarification. The first grader was wrong about using `fs.touch` but i still need to create the user input function for touch. What should I do there?

Comment: What is wrong with the function you created? Are your instructors being unhelpful on purpose? It seems they are not being clear with the requirements of your task, or you are not understanding what they are asking for.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger well I figured it out. A lot based on what you said where there isn't an `fs.touch` but I'm slowly learning that I should've gone with a different course or program. Luckily my mentor is awesome and has gone above and beyond so he himself has made it worth it. But You did help a ton! Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help, good luck with your program!

Answer (score 1):

Make `time` either the current time or the time you want to be set:

```
fs.utimesSync(filename, time, time);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just open the path file in write mode, and close it. You will have an empty file, equivalent at touch in command line

Comment: I tried that my graders want me to actually create a file.